# Create a script to convert octal permission of given file to symbolic permission

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to create a script which will take the a file name as an argument and print its permission in the symbolic form.

suppose the octal permission is 755 the script must convert it to

owner  - rwx
group  - r-x
others - r-x

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe I have already posted my code in the answer section.

Comment: I can see that, but this still isn't an acceptable question.

Answer (score 1):

import os

```
permissionDict ={
  'access':{
    '0':('---'),
    '1':('--x'),
    '2':('-w-'),
    '3':('-wx'),
    '4':('r--'),
    '5':('r-x'),
    '6':('rw-'),
    '7':('rwx')
  },

  'roles':{
    0:'owner',
    1:'group',
    2:'other'
  }  
}

fname = input('Enter a file Name : ')
if os.path.exists(fname):
  permissionOctal = oct(os.lstat(fname).st_mode)[-3:] #645
  for role,octal in enumerate(permissionOctal): # [(0,6) , (1,4) , (2,5)]
    print(permissionDict['roles'][role],permissionDict['access'][octal])
else:
  print('File not found..!')
```

**RESULT**

> Enter a file Name :  /tmp

```
owner rwx
group rwx
other rwx
```

> Enter a file Name :  /etc/shadow

```
owner rw-
group r--
other ---
```

Comment: If you've just written some code you want to share, consider an account on GitHub or publish it on PyPI; self-answered questions must still be *good questions*. Also it's probably worth a visit to [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0):

```
def octal_to_string(octal):
result = ""
value_letters = [(4, "r"), (2, "w"), (1, "x")]
for permissions in [int(n) for n in str(octal)]:
    for value, letter in value_letters:
        if permissions >= value: # 
            result += letter
            permissions -= value # 
        else:
            result += "-"
return result
```